# SQL transforming one row to columns with unknown number of distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a following database

```
id  item_id  date        system_code  value
#1  0001     01-01-2019  0999         10
#2  0001     02-01-2019  0888         15
#3  0001     01-01-2019  0999         10
#4  0002     02-01-2019  0777         20
#5  0002     03-01-2019  0777         35
```

And the result I want to achieve would look like so, with values for system_code columns being sum of "value"

```
  item_id  date        0999  0888  0777
  0001     01-01-2019  20        
  0001     02-01-2019        15
  0002     02-01-2019              20
  0002     03-01-2019              35
```

My problem is that there is over 1000 distinct values for system_code so I can't type them by hand.
Database has nearly billion entries so anything that would calculate quickly would be perfect.

Comment: Why Tag SQL Server and Oracle SQL Developer? Those 2 have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a DYNAMIC PIVOT.   Over 1,000 columns seems like a requirement flaw

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, here is a dynamic PIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = stuff((Select distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME([system_code]) 
                                     From YourTable
                                     Order By 1 Desc
                                    For XML Path('') )
                                   ,1,1,'') 

Set @SQL = '
Select *
 From  ( Select item_id,date,system_code,value from YourTable ) src
 Pivot ( sum(value) for system_Code in ( '+ @SQL + ') ) pvt
'

--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Note:**

I believe the max number of columns is 1,024 (wide table 30,000).

Personally, I would hate to consume more than 50 columns.

**EDIT:**

If you have two many columns, you can filter the list by adding a WHERE in the first query and perhaps run it twice (or more).  The results would have the same number of rows, just different column sets.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = stuff((Select distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME([system_code]) 
                                   From #YourTable
                                   Where [system_code] >'0500' -- or any appropriate filter
                                   Order By 1 desc
                                   For XML Path('') )
                                  ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: This is just perfect, thank you so much for the code and helpful tips!

Comment: @A67John always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id, date,
       max(case when system_code = '0999' then value end) as value_0999,
       max(case when system_code = '0888' then value end) as value_0888,
       max(case when system_code = '0777' then value end) as value_0777
from t
group by item_id, date;
```

You can generate this `max()` expressions using a query:

```
select distinct
       replace('max(case when system_code = '<val>' then value end) as value_<val>,',
               '<val>', system_code
              )
from t;
```

Comment: It would have to be 
sum(case when system_code = '0999' then value end) as value_0999,
if I'm thinking right

Comment: @A67John . . . Your sample data does not have any duplicates for a given `item_id`/`date`, so either `max()` or `sum()` works there.   However, use `sum()` if that is appropriate for your actual problem.